# Ctrl+Z Character and EOF Issues With Pipes

Tags: perl

I have a huge file provided by a third party, which appears to have been generated in a Windows/DOS-like environment. The last line of the file contains a `^Z` character. I noticed this when I looked at the processed file and the last line contained a `^Z`. I added some logic to skip this line from the input and it was working fine until I changed my code to take the input from `stdin` as opposed to a file.

Here is a simpler illustration of this issue. When I do a line count on a single file stream with and without `^Z` skipping, it reports the correct values:

```
unzip -j -p -qq file1.zip | perl -nle 'print' | wc -l
3451
unzip -j -p -qq file2.zip | perl -nle 'print' | wc -l
3451

unzip -j -p -qq file1.zip | perl -nle 'next if /^\cZ/; print' | wc -l
3450
unzip -j -p -qq file2.zip | perl -nle 'next if /^\cZ/; print' | wc -l
3450
```

Now when I try to process both files at once, I lose one record. I am guessing this is something to do with the `^Z` character but I cannot figure out what I can do about it:

```
unzip -j -p -qq '*.zip' | perl -nle 'print' | wc -l
6901  ## this should have been 6902 

unzip -j -p -qq '*.zip' | perl -nle 'next if /^\cZ/; print' | wc -l
6899  ## this should have been 6900
```

These files are huge (each 20+GB) and they are to be read in groups of 3-6 files so I wanted to avoid processing them one by one and then concatenate later. Any thoughts on how to avoid the `^Z` character without running into the above issue?

I am on a Linux machine. Btw, opening the file in `vim` does not display the last record (i.e., `^Z`) and setting `set ff=unix` did not change this either. So `vim` reports `3450` lines for the single unzipped file and `6900` for the combined unzipped files.

Thanks!

Comment: @TLP Unfortunately, I have no control over the input file. The puzzling thing is why is this an issue only when the files are combined.  Not sure why perl skips a non-EOF line just because there is an EOF character (shouldn't it just start the next file?) I know I can switch to a shell script wrapper with `for` but I thought I will use `gnu parallel` next and stdin -> stdout makes that easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `^Z` isn't followed by a line ending, `unzip` is producing

```
 file1:1
 file1:2
 file1:3
 ^Zfile2:1
 file2:2
 file2:3
 ^Z
```

so you delete the first line of the second file. You could simply remove the `^Z` instead of the entire line.

```
perl -pe's/^\cZ//'
```

That said, `unzip -a` is designed for exactly this situation. Not only will it strip the `^Z` for you, it will also fix the line endings if necessary.

```
$ unzip -j -p -qq z.zip a.txt | od -c
0000000   a   b   c  \r  \n   d   e   f  \r  \n 032
0000013

$ unzip -j -p -qq z.zip b.txt | od -c
0000000   g   h   i  \r  \n   j   k   l  \r  \n 032
0000013

$ unzip -j -p -qq z.zip | od -c
0000000   a   b   c  \r  \n   d   e   f  \r  \n 032   g   h   i  \r  \n
0000020   j   k   l  \r  \n 032
0000026

$ unzip -j -p -qq -a z.zip | od -c
0000000   a   b   c  \n   d   e   f  \n   g   h   i  \n   j   k   l  \n
0000020
```

Comment: Thank you@ikegami. You are amazing -- it never occurred to me that unzip will roll the next line forward and that's what's causing the issue. I guess I may have been better off deleting the `^Z` in code instead of skipping. In my test file `-a` fixes the problem. My actual program takes many hours so will verify that next.

Comment: (Who uses Ctrl-Z in this day and age!??! That's been obsolete for at least 25 years!!!!!)

Comment: I know! This comes from a vendor that uses very, very old machines (my guess is mainframe or VAX or something like that) to create these data files. Unfortunately, I don't have any control over their file creation process.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the file creation process. Converting the file as they cross system boundaries is appropriate.